# Matrix Operations with Specific Columns in data.frame

Tags: r, qualtrics

I have a squirrelly dataset drawn from a Qualtrics survey. It looks like this:

```
V3       Q8_42  Q8_33  Q8_72   Q8_38  Q13_1_42 Q13_1_33 Q13_1_72 Q13_1_38
Chap A     .    1       .        .       .      4        .        .
Chap B     1    .       .        .       4      .        .        .
Chap C     .    .       .        .       .      .        .        .
Chap D     .    .       .        .       .      .        .        .
```

The snapshot shows four individuals asked if they are friends (q8_42 is A; q8_33 is B, q8_72 is C, and q8_38 is D). If someone says they are friends then they are asked about the strength of their friendship on a 1-5 scale (q13_1_42 is for A, q13_1_33 is for B, q13_1_72 is for C, and q13_1_38 is for D). In all I have 95 individuals and there are in all 9 questions posed to them re: their friendship. How should I be running matrix operations such that I end up with the following matrix, 1 per friendship question:

```
       Chap A   Chap B  Chap C  Chap D
Chap A  0       4       .       .
Chap B  4       0       .       .
Chap C  .       .       0       .
Chap D  .       .       .       0
```

My solution has been to read the data (named "kolp") into R, then run

```
Chap.A <- (kolp$q8_42 * kolp$q13_1_42)
Chap.B <- (kolp$q8_33 * kolp$q13_1_33)
Chap.C <- (kolp$q8_72 * kolp$q13_1_72)
Chap.D <- (kolp$q8_38 * kolp$q13_1_38)
Mat.1 <- cbind(Chap.A, Chap.B, Chap.C, Chap.D)
rownames(Mat.1) <- c("Chap.A", "Chap.B", "Chap.C", "Chap.D")
```

This gives me

```
         Chap.A Chap.B Chap.C Chap.D
Chap.A     NA      4     NA     NA
Chap.B      4     NA     NA     NA
Chap.C     NA     NA     NA     NA
Chap.D     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

But I know this is the clunky way to go about it, especially with 9 matrices to extract as *.csv or *.txt files, with dim of 95x95

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are in the form "questionID_individualID", you can try this function to process your data:

```
f <- function(dat)
{
    n <- names(dat)

    id <- substring(n, nchar(n)-1)

    qu_id <- substring(n, 1, nchar(n)-3)

    individuals <- sort(unique(id))

    questions <- unique(qu_id)

    result <- 1

    for(q in questions)
    {
        filter <- qu_id==q

        result <- result * dat[,filter][,match(individuals, id[filter])]
    }

    result

    colnames(result) <- individuals

    result
}
```

use as `f(kolp)`. It works even if the columns are out of order. But it will fail (or give wrong results) if some questions do not have columns for all individuals.

Comment: thanks @Ferdinand.kraft ... I'll give it a whirl today and see how it works.